# Call a function after all slides in jquery cycle are loaded

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to call a function after **all slides** in  jquery cycle slider are loaded. on the options page of plugin's website http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html I found out an option called **after** which can be used to call a function after each slides are loaded. but I want a function to be called when **all** slides are loaded and **not each** slides.

*I added alert("hello") in onAfter(), and I see alert hello after every pager clicks. which i really dont want.*

Following cycle initialization is used by me.

```
    $('#lb_main-slide').cycle({ 
            fx:     'fade',
            speed:  '100', 
            timeout: 0, 
            startingSlide: index,
            pager:  '#lb-slidethumbs', 
            pagerAnchorBuilder: imagepager2,
            after: onAfter,
            requeueOnImageNotLoaded: true
            });
```

Is there any possible way where I can call a single function once all slides are loaded successfully ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you say "after all slides are loaded", do you mean the DOM + all images are loaded, or when all slides have been displayed?

Comment: hi @AndersHolmström I don't mean DOM + all images. I mean when jquery cycle function is completed successfully. I'm calling this cycle plugin on lightbox so I initialize this function onclick lightbox triggers.

Comment: But the cycle never does 'finish' does it? It's a cycle, so it just goes around, around, around... Do you want a function to be called then cycle is stopped, or when it reaches the last image in the set to be cycled through?

Comment: Yea @AndersHolmström you have a point there.. Or I would like to have a function which is called just once after the cycle is loaded . (Like function called using after option but only once)

Comment: Seems like you just want to be able to execute more JavaScript after you call cycle() on an object? Can you try to explain what you're actually trying to do instead?

Comment: It turned out that I wanted to call my function after all the thumbs in my cycle were built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to solve this problem I called my function in core jquery.cycle.all.js file, in

```
function buildPager(els, opts)
```

after

```
opts.updateActivePagerLink(opts.pager, opts.startingSlide, opts.activePagerClass);
```

So I called my function after cycle's pager was built.
And it worked for me perfectly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. But I read about there being different types of functions in JavaScript. I realized that I was trying to pass in a reference to a global function to the 'after' attribute. That did not work.

Try doing something like this:

```
    $('#images').cycle({
         timeout: 5000,
         fx:'fade',
         after: (function() {
             MyClass.performNow();
         })
    });
```